# Bootstrap js elements work in Fiddle but not locally

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've done nearly everything I can think of, but I can't get my bootstrap elements (namely the nav collapse and the tabs) to work locally. They all work beautifully in fiddle, so I'm pretty confused.

the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/e4RZE/3/

and my code for bringing the js into my project is below the footer, like so:

```
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

my code for the header is as follows:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button> <a class="brand" href="http://howard.edu">Project</a>

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="nowplaying.html">Now Playing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Public Resources <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="public.html#observatory">Observatory</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="public.html#planetarium">Planetarium</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="nav-header">For Teachers and Schools</li>
                        <li><a href="schools.html#programs">Programs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="schools.html#events">Host an Event</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="schools.html#education">Educational Initiatives</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Undergraduate Resources <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="students.html#observatory">Observatory</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="students.html#planetarium">Planetarium</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="nav-header">HU Physics</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Physics Homepage</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Physics and Astronomy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Bootstrap.css, bootstrap-responsive.css and my custom file (betterstrap2.css) are added like so:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700 ' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/betterstrap2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you including the `bootstrap.css` locally?

Comment: like so: `<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700 ' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="css/betterstrap2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Can you clarify "doens't work"? Is the navbar not responsive? Does nothing happen when you click on the tabs?

Comment: @Skelly When I click on the three lines, the navbar expands, but it won't contract. Further, when I click on a dropdown menu while the navbar is expanded (ie: public resources) it doesn't expand the rest of the navbar... instead, it just displays as much as possible in the remaining room.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your jquery and bootstrap source files are located in the correct location to be loaded from those script tags.

Also, you should be loading the bootstrap.css file as well, if you want to actually see your bootstrapped elements looking pretty on the page :)

Comment: They should be in the right folder, and I referenced them just like I did my css, and _that_ works... gah!

Answer (score -1):

There are javascript errors or links to javascript files that are invalid. Hit F12 on the page and refresh to see what is failing.

Comment: That is my answer. Hit F12 and fix the javascript errors or bad resource urls.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer